# React - How to display converted datetime?

Tags: reactjs, date, time, locale

In react app, I am getting an timestamp like `1635424532797` and I am converting and trying to display a date using `new Date(1635424532797).toLocaleDateString("en-US")`.
Right now I am getting `Invalid Date` for this.

I am getting `createdAt` timestamp from backend data and parsing it to Date function.

How can I display a date (or datetime) here? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you maybe post a bit of code? When I run `new Date(1635424532797).toLocaleDateString("en-US")` in the Chrome dev console it returns **"10/28/2021"**

Comment: Yes, same result I got from browser console but not through the code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, can you please provide more infos (code) on where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to do Date in javascript, sample does new Date object with string and formats to en-GB

```
const date = new Date(YOURDATE)
date.setDate(date.getDate());
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
}).replace(/ /g, ' ');
```

Comment: This didn't support.